# Direction of resizing popup control and it’s content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my solution, I have a custom popup control that is set according to personal requirements and my only problem occurs when I move my app to the right side of the screen and then I define a custom width(which is good) but my content is resized on the left side and my `CustomPopupPlacementCallback` is not working(clip attached). Finally, to confirm, I want my content to be resized from the right side of the popup without moving the popup over the parent which is grid defined near it. Any suggestions on how to define that?

My popup has a border and inside it a stack panel where I have some texblocks controls and that is it.

```
<Popup>
<Border BorderThickness="0" Background="{DynamicResource RegularButtonBrush}" Padding="3,15,0,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
  <StackPanel x:Name="popupSideMenuLabels" Orientation="Vertical" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Loogout"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Manage"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Logbook"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Notifications"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Cell Settings"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblogbook" Text="Reports"/>

  </StackPanel>
</Border>
</Popup>
```

To confirm, my textblocks together with the popup control are being shown as on the video clip but I want two shirk the right side of popup if the default width is bigger than new defined(space reaming between the parent control grid and the right end of the screen) what literally means to have "Lo" of "Logbook" or "Ma" or "Manage" and for example "No" instead of "Notifications" and so on.

UPDATE - CODE

```
        var taskBarHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
        var screenHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - taskBarHeight;
        var screenWidht = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 40; //40 pixels is width of parent
        var gridPoint = sideMenuGrid.PointFromScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        
        var gridSizeHeight = gridPoint.Y < 0
                                        ? screenHeight - (-gridPoint.Y)
                                        : screenHeight - gridPoint.Y;
        var gridSizeWidth = gridPoint.X < 0
                                    ? screenWidht - (-gridPoint.X)
                                    : screenWidht - gridPoint.X;
        mypopup.Height = gridSizeHeight;
    
    if (DefaultSideMenuWidth - gridSizeWidth < 0) // Not at the edge of the screen
        sideMenuGrid.FindVisualChild<NonTopmostPopup>("PART_Popup").Width = DEFAULT_SIDE_MENU_WIDTH;
    else // At the edge of the screen
    {                    
        sideMenuGrid.FindVisualChild<NonTopmostPopup>("PART_Popup").Width = gridSizeWidth;
    }
```

With this code, I am achieving vertical height if the app is below the taskbar. The same goes for width where I achieve to get the width but it is not being shrinked from the right as I want it to be shrinked.

[image]

UPDATE(RIGHT SIDE):

so, if i move my app to the right side and for example my side menu parent(which is a grid) is being showed half of the size the same things occurs where my popup has a full size when it comes to height but still the left side of the app is swallowed for some reason.

Comment: Could you show actual minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @emoacht provided and i just wanted to know if anyone had the same situation when it comes to shrinking direction and that is it.

Comment: Your XAML is not still actual code, isn't it? In addition, why you posted the code for height when you are talking about width?

Comment: @emoacht i am defining everything from the code behind(mouse enter, mouse leave event handlers and similar and in XAML i only have defined control with children which is already a custom popup that inherits from the popup class). anyway, i mentioned only height because it is working and the same code with width is also working(as on the video clip i attached) but i wanted someone to think and provide me some useful information and that is it.

Comment: @emoacht to confirm one more time, my width is good(and i added that) but the content of the popup is shrinking on the left side(which looks normal because there is visible space) but with a defined CustomPopupPlacementCallback it still tries to move on the left and finally it goes above parent which is literally overriding setting from CustomPopupPlacementCallback defined property and that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating everything by yourself, you can create a custom control like the [SplitView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.splitview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) in WinUI 3.

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSplitViewExample">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SplitView}">
        <Setter Property="OpenPaneLength" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="CompactPaneLength" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="PaneBackground" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SplitView}">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    x:Name="PaneColumn"
                                    Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="PaneBorder"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding PaneBackground}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />
                            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**SplitView.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfSplitViewExample;

[ContentProperty(nameof(Content))]
public class SplitView : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPaneOpenProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         nameof(IsPaneOpen),
         typeof(bool),
         typeof(SplitView),
         new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
         {
             if (d is SplitView splitView &&
                e.NewValue is bool isPaneOpen)
             {
                 if (isPaneOpen is true)
                 { 
                     splitView.OpenPane();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     splitView.ClosePane();
                 }
             }
         }));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenPaneLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(OpenPaneLength),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(SplitView),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, (d, e) => (d as SplitView)?.UpdatePaneLength()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompactPaneLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(CompactPaneLength),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(SplitView),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, (d, e) => (d as SplitView)?.UpdatePaneLength()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PaneProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Pane),
            typeof(UIElement),
            typeof(SplitView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) => (d as SplitView)?.UpdatePaneContent()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Content),
            typeof(UIElement),
            typeof(SplitView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) => (d as SplitView)?.UpdateContent()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PaneBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(PaneBackground),
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(SplitView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    static SplitView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(SplitView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SplitView)));
    }

    public Brush PaneBackground
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(PaneBackgroundProperty);
        set => SetValue(PaneBackgroundProperty, value);
    }

    public UIElement Content
    {
        get => (UIElement)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }

    public UIElement Pane
    {
        get => (UIElement)GetValue(PaneProperty);
        set => SetValue(PaneProperty, value);
    }

    public bool IsPaneOpen
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPaneOpenProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsPaneOpenProperty, value);
    }

    public double OpenPaneLength
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(OpenPaneLengthProperty);
        set => SetValue(OpenPaneLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public double CompactPaneLength
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CompactPaneLengthProperty);
        set => SetValue(CompactPaneLengthProperty, value);
    }

    private ColumnDefinition? PaneColumn { get; set; }

    private Border? PaneBorder { get; set; }

    private Border? ContentBorder { get; set; }

    public event RoutedEventHandler? PaneOpened;

    public event RoutedEventHandler? PaneClosed;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(PaneColumn)) is ColumnDefinition paneColumn)
        {
            PaneColumn = paneColumn;
        }

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(PaneBorder)) is Border paneBorder)
        {
            PaneBorder = paneBorder;
        }

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(ContentBorder)) is Border contentBorder)
        {
            ContentBorder = contentBorder;
        }

        UpdatePaneLength();
        UpdatePaneContent();
        UpdateContent();
    }

    private void OpenPane()
    {
        if (PaneColumn is not null)
        {
            PaneColumn.Width = new GridLength(OpenPaneLength);
            PaneOpened?.Invoke(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void ClosePane()
    {
        if (PaneColumn is not null)
        {
            PaneColumn.Width = new GridLength(CompactPaneLength);
            PaneClosed?.Invoke(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePaneLength()
    {
        if (PaneColumn is not null)
        {
            PaneColumn.Width = IsPaneOpen is true
                ? new GridLength(OpenPaneLength)
                : new GridLength(CompactPaneLength);
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePaneContent()
    {
        if (PaneBorder is not null)
        {
            PaneBorder.Child = Pane;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateContent()
    {
        if (ContentBorder is not null)
        {
            ContentBorder.Child = Content;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfSplitViewExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSplitViewExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    Topmost="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="IsPaneOpenToggleButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Content="Is pane open" />
        <local:SplitView
            Grid.Row="1"
            IsPaneOpen="{Binding ElementName=IsPaneOpenToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"
            PaneBackground="Yellow"
            PaneClosed="SplitView_PaneClosed"
            PaneOpened="SplitView_PaneOpened">
            <local:SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Logout" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Manage" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Logbook" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Notifications" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Cell Settings" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Reports" />
                </StackPanel>
            </local:SplitView.Pane>
            <TextBlock Text="Contents goes here." />
        </local:SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: this could work but i don’t have access to the solution to be honest and it is a long story to be honest again @Andrew.